# Casting IList<T1> to ILIst<T2>

Tags: c#, list, linq, oop, casting

Trying to cast like this

```
Products1 = (IList<ProductInfo>)basicProfile.Products2.Select(ToProductInfo)
```

Products1 is a

```
public IList<ProductInfo> Products { get; set; }
```

Product2 is a

```
public IList<Product> Products { get; }
```

Here is the method I apply on every elem of Product2

```
internal static ProductInfo ToProductInfo(Product product)
    {
        if (product == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return new ProductInfo
        {
            Id = product.Id,
            EffectiveTimestamp = product.EffectiveTimestamp,
            ExpiryTimestamp = product.ExpiryTimestamp
        };
    }
```

Product and ProductInfo have the same structure and are almost identical

I am catching this

```
System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 
'SelectArrayIterator`2[Domain.Product,WebApi.Contracts.ProductInfo]' to type 
'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[WebApi.Contracts.ProductInfo]'.
```

Morever it doesn't even get into ToProductInfo method

Comment: Simpy call `ToList` instead of casting, as `Select` will return an `IEnumerable<T>`, not a `List<T>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to the way linq work (defered execution) the Select, create a IEnumerable

what you want to achieve can be done by adding a ToList()

```
Products1 = basicProfile.Products2.Select(ToProductInfo).ToList()
```

or depending on your use case, Define Products1 as

```
public IEnumerable<ProductInfo> Products { get; set; }
```

for more information, this page 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx and the part on Deferred Query Evaluation

this allow you to chain linq queries without iterating many times your collection